# How to dynamically create scenes in JavaFX?

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx

[image: People Table]

So I've built a TableView in JavaFX as shown in the image (People Table) consisting of a list of names. For the final program, the info could be imported from a database so we do not know the number of people beforehand.

My question is how do I dynamically create a scene for each person so when the detail button is clicked on, it would switch to a unique scene so I can subsequently add info on that specific person (telephone number, address etc)?

Many thanks. Code below for reference:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.*;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.event.*;
import javafx.geometry.*;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.stage.*;
import javafx.util.Callback;

public class cutExample extends Application {
  public static void main(String[] args) { launch(args); }


  @Override public void start(final Stage stage) {
    stage.setTitle("People");

    // create a table.
    final TableView<Person> table = new TableView<>(
      FXCollections.observableArrayList(
        new Person("Jacob", "Smith"),
        new Person("Isabella", "Johnson"),
        new Person("Ethan", "Williams"),
        new Person("Emma", "Jones"),
        new Person("Michael", "Brown")
      )
    );

    // define the table columns.
    TableColumn<Person, String> firstNameCol = new TableColumn<>("First Name");
    firstNameCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("firstName"));
    TableColumn<Person, String> lastNameCol = new TableColumn<>("Last Name");
    lastNameCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("lastName"));
    TableColumn<Person, Boolean> actionCol = new TableColumn<>("Action");
    actionCol.setSortable(false);


    // create a cell value factory with a details button for each row in the table.
    actionCol.setCellFactory(new Callback<TableColumn<Person, Boolean>, TableCell<Person, Boolean>>() {
      @Override public TableCell<Person, Boolean> call(TableColumn<Person, Boolean> personBooleanTableColumn) {
        return new AddPersonCell(stage, table);
      }
    });

    table.getColumns().setAll(firstNameCol, lastNameCol, actionCol);
    table.setColumnResizePolicy(TableView.CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY);

    stage.setScene(new Scene(table));
    stage.show();
  }

  /** A table cell containing a button for details on each person. */
  private class AddPersonCell extends TableCell<Person, Boolean> {
    // a button for a specific person's details
    final Button details       = new Button("Details");
    // pads and centers the button in the cell.
    final StackPane paddedButton = new StackPane();


    /**
     * AddPersonCell constructor
     * @param stage the stage in which the table is placed.
     * @param table the table to which a new person can be added.
     */
    AddPersonCell(final Stage stage, final TableView table) {
      paddedButton.setPadding(new Insets(3));
      paddedButton.getChildren().add(details);


    }

    /** places an details button in the row only if the row is not empty. */
    @Override protected void updateItem(Boolean item, boolean empty) {
      super.updateItem(item, empty);
      if (!empty) {
        setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.GRAPHIC_ONLY);
        setGraphic(paddedButton);
      } else {
        setGraphic(null);
      }
    }
  }


}
```

Comment: By scene what exactly do you mean?  For example do you mean a new window pops up?

Comment: No, I would like to keep the same stage (window) but to switch scenes. The scene is just the content inside the window.
https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/Scene.html

But in this case I guess it doesn't matter too much if you can provide a solution for creating a new window that pops up it would pretty much answer the query since I can configure this for the scene.

Comment: Which particular part are you stuck on? You have already set one scene in the window, so presumably you know how to set another scene in the window. Is the question "how do I execute some code when a button is pressed?" Or are you stuck somewhere else? (If so, where?)

Comment: I know how to manually declare each individual scene, but in this case we do not know the number of people that will populate this list. 
So I want to know how to set up the program such that a scene will be created dynamically for each person.